# updating sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

sir, i have a problem in updating my database. i've made a listview containing this data

```
name
phone number
status
```

i would like to update the status of person if he sent a message with a keyword "available" in it and would update my listview like this

```
name
phone number
available
```

so i decided to make the phone number as the trigger. if the phone number of the person who sent the message is in my listview, it will update the database. but here is my problem, if i saved the phone number in my listview in this format

```
09211234567
```

the sender will return their phone number as

```
+639211234567
```

so i worked around this by getting the substring and cut the phone number into "9211234567", and then add 0 to transform it into "09211234567".

however, the database status still doesn't update. but when i used the same technique in sending sms from emulator to emulator, it works just fine.

i saved the number of emulator in my listview as

```
5556
```

but the emulator returns

```
15555215556
```

so i just get the substring to get 5556

please help me. here is my code:

```
public static String sender;
public GroupDb info;
public String aStatus = "available";
public String nStatus = "not available";
public String addNum = "0";
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    info = new GroupDb(context);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<pdusObj.length; i++) 
    { 
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu ((byte[]) 
            pdusObj[i]); 
            sender = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    } 

    for (SmsMessage msg : messages) {
        if (msg.getMessageBody().contains("available")) {
            info.open();

            String remFirstChar = sender.substring(3);
            addNum += remFirstChar;
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "received sms from: " +addNum,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //if starts with +639
            if(sender.length() == 13)
            {
                info.updateStatus(addNum, aStatus);
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "addNum: " +addNum,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "sender: " +sender,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                info.updateStatus(remFirstChar, aStatus);
            }
            info.close();
        }//end if - available
```

here is how i updated my status

```
//update status
public void updateStatus(String mNumber, String mStatus) throws SQLException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_STATUS, mStatus);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NUMBER + "=" + mNumber, null);
}
```

update:
i even tried to enter "+63" format in listview but still, i won't update. all functions such as deletion and editing also don't work and shows force close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `PhoneNumberUtils` class.

Before saving the Phone Number in database first convert it as

```
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phonenumber);
```

For comparison you can use [PhoneNumberUtils.compare](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: so that's it! thanks. at first, i tried to remove the first char which is 0 or +63 in the phone number then saved it to database, then displayed it in my listview with 0 in it. it also worked.